# Add css display block after a delay function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

In a sequence of animations I have a small bug I can't figure out. I am running delays for different parts of the animation to sequence them in. For those divs, I style them to `display:none` and then I fade them in after their delay.

Well for this particular animation, I am toggle sliding a "mask" off of it, so not fading anything in like normal. This is causing an overlapping over my other divs to where I thought originally it was a z-index issue well, not that's not the case. The problem is, I am not displaying none because I am not initiallizing it with a `fadeIn`, so the `background-color` always shows and disrupts other elements.

This is blue background overtop of the teal is the `background-color` of the `home-learn` div....

[image]

I need help figuring out how I keep my div `home-learn` displaying none until the delay has processed and then to display it somwhow.

Here is the code:

```
#home-learn {
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2.3em;
    z-index: 99;
    display: none;
}
#curtain-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0085A1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}   

$(function(){
    $('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');
    $("#curtain-div").delay(15800).toggle("slide", {
        direction: "right"
      }, 1000);
});

<div id="home-learn">
        <div id="curtain-div"></div>
        Discover more...
    </div>
```

I need to figure out how I can make `$('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');` work after the delay.

If you need to see this live, comment below and I will add the site.

UPDATE - ADDED HTML

```
<div class="blue">
        <div id="hand-wrap"><img src="/images/hand.png" class="hand" alt="HELLO"></div>
        <span class="hand-text">HELLO</span>
        <div class="circle">
            <div class="spinner top topright"></div>
            <div class="spinner top topleft"></div>
            <div class="spinner bottom bottomleft"></div>
            <div class="spinner bottom bottomright"></div>
            <div class="mask q2"></div>
            <div class="mask q4"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="circle-text">We're Optimum<br>Designs</div>
        <div class="aqua">
            <div id="aqua-text1">We transform ideas...</div>
            <div id="aqua-text2">...into reality.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="blue-home-text">We build beautiful, engaging sites for companies both large and small.</div>
        <div id="home-learn">
            <div id="curtain-div"></div>
            Discover more...
        </div>
```

Comment: You need `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Tushar How would I make it work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this question:

> I need to figure out how I can make `$('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');` work after the delay.

Add the line just after the delay method with [`queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method:

```
$("#curtain-div").delay(15800).queue(function() {
     $('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');
}).toggle("slide", {
     direction: "right"
}, 1000);
```

### EDIT

To proof this works, I add a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/4vLLnxt1/

You must to see the blue box appears after the 4 seconds of delay. That works perfectly.

### Second EDIT

Due the comments below, try changing with this:

```
$("#curtain-div").delay(15800).queue(function() {
     $('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');
     $(this).toggle("slide", {
          direction: "right"
     }, 1000);
});
```

### Third EDIT

As we talk in comments, all is solved with `next` parameter. The whole code:

```
$("#curtain-div").delay(15800).queue(function(next) {
     $('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');
     next();
}).toggle("slide", {
     direction: "right"
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This doesn't show the div though. I don't think the css display block works.

Comment: It works perfectly. Depending of your HTML, maybe you have a wrong markup. Share the HTML because this answer works perfectly.

Comment: Perez Gude More of the html shown. This doesn't show the background color anymore, just the wording doesn't show up when it should or at all. See it live here:: http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index  .... The last sequence where you see the circle arrow is where the text "discover more" should appear.

Comment: In your live site I see that `#home-learn` is setting with `display:block` in the `style` attribute, then **this answer works**. Other thing is why this doesn't appears, and this is produced by the `#curtain-div` that is above the text. If you remove `<div id="curtain-div">`  you'll see magic!!! The text is shown.

Comment: In CSS is display:none. But in the `style` html attribute it turns to block. It works perfectly, trust in me. To see what I said to you, please, add this to your CSS: `#curtain-div { position: relative; }` and you'll see the message appears.

Comment: Maybe I need to make some screenshots of your site to show this to you. The problem is simple: the `curtain div` is **ABOVE** the text of `home-learn`, so you can't see never the `home-learn` while `curtain div` is 
**ABOVE**

Comment: the curtain div is not sliding , it's because the text doesn't show.

Comment: I understand `curtain div` is above. That is the point. It slides off of the words, to give it a look of the wording typing in. That is the whole point of this `.toggle("slide", {
     direction: "right"
}, 1000);`

Comment: What could I do then to make this curtain div function work like it should and show the text?

Comment: I don't know how `toggle()` works with directions, I guess it's neccessary a plugin or some things, but I know the `animate()` method, that you can achieve the same: https://jsfiddle.net/4vLLnxt1/1/

Comment: It seems that directions in `toggle()` method needs to include jQuery UI library (not single jQuery). Are you including that?

Comment: Yes I have the UI library. This worked perfectly before, I just had the overlapping background color over all other sequences. That is why I was trying to display none until the delay. Now it won't work at all. Look at my site now.

Comment: Please, try the second edition of this answer. I move inside the queue the toggle, and must work now. Tell me if this solves, please.

Comment: I insist. The problem is the curtain-div, that is not making anything, I try with animate and it don't works, but in fiddle it works. So you have another code that enters in conflict with that. For your question: `I need to figure out how I can make $('#home-learn').css('display', 'block'); work after the delay.` this answer solves that. You can upvote at least this answer but I can't help you more. If you remove the curtain-div it works perfectly. If you need an effect, it's better another effect.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help. I just don't see why anything else in my code would not make this work? As I showed you, when I use my original code that I put in this question, my curtain div slides off. I just don't get why it won't slide off with your code.

Comment: The slide function is exactly as yours, but I move it to another place. Debugger reaches that line but it doesn't make anything. I can't try nothing in your page since there aren't a fiddle to try it. Maybe you need to play with `next` parameter in the `queue()` method (`.....queue(function(next) { ..... next(); });`)

Comment: Where did you see the curtain was working fine? I try to animate it with the console outside of queue() method and it doesn't works ....

Comment: It works with my original code. The only issue was the background color was showing over everything else because it is displaying block and not waiting until after the delay to show. See my site now.. this is the original code.

Comment: Any idea why it works in my original code, but not yours?

Comment: I don't know, I think it's because the `next` parameter that I said to you before, but a question: if your code works, why you need to change?

Comment: Because I can't have the `home-learn` div displaying until after the delay. Right now the `background-color` of it shows over all the rest of my sequence.

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you more, because I am unable to edit the code in your page and you don't provide a working fiddle / snippet to allow us to edit it and identify the problem, and test another solutions if it's working. Since I request that fiddle and you don't provide it, I can't help you more. Maybe you need to read the rules of stackoverflow first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that's an interesting article.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your request. Here you are...a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=tyaxqqfgTx

Comment: Random question, does the queue and next function work in a mobile setting?

Comment: Yeah, it's dependent of jQuery, not the device you are using